# What does this displacement time graph say about velocity?

Tags: kinematics, time, displacement

[image]

I have a debate with my sister, who says that velocity should be constant because velocity is $\dfrac{d}{t}$ and there certainly is some non-zero displacement. I say velocity is the rate of change of displacement, so it should be $0$. How do I convince her? Any illustrations or better way to explain this to a ninth grader?

Comment: Couldn't you at least post a better quality image? What is the $y$-axis supposed to be?

Comment: @ThePointer I guess I've written displacement time graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the graph, the displacement does not change. If this graph described a car, then you can imagine a car parked in your garage, and ten seconds later, it is still parked in your garage at that exact same position. The car did not move whatsoever. Its velocity would be zero.

As for the definition for velocity, it is **not** $\dfrac{d}{t}$.

Suppose $\mathbf {\vec r}$ is the position of an object. The definition of velocity is the derivative with respect to time of position, $$\mathbf{\vec v} = \dfrac{\mathrm d \mathbf{\vec r}}{\mathrm d t}$$

Now, as a 9th grader, you likely don't know what that is, so, instead, take this definition of average velocity
$$\mathbf{\vec v}_{\text{average}} = \dfrac{\mathrm \Delta \mathbf{\vec r}}{\mathrm \Delta t}$$

The key takeaway is that velocity is $\rm \dfrac{{\bf change} \ in \ position}{change \ in \ time}$, which is very different from position/time. Your position may be non-zero, but your change in position is definitely zero.

In your 1-dimensional case, velocity will be the slope of your $d$ vs $t$ graph, which is clearly zero.

Comment: Amazing explanation thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You could say **R** Represents displacement and the tip of the vector is the body whose motion we analyze as **R** does not change with time the tip of the vector stays at the same place as time progresses which means its velocity is zero.

If she did not learn vectors yet you could still give the same explanation just without a coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Your sister defined velocity the wronged way. For starters,  you can start by correctly defining the definition velocity. [See here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity#:%7E:text=The%20velocity%20of%20an%20object,%2Fh%20to%20the%20north).